# MATLAB - extract array values based on conditions

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, indexing, conditional-statements

I have 4x4  matrix A

```
[1 2 3 4;
 2 2 2 3;
 5 5 5 5;
 4 4 4 4]
```

I know how to locate all values less than 4. A<4. But I'm not sure how to write an 'if' statement for; three or more values, all which are less than 4, contained in the same row. For instance; see above A(1,:) and A(2,:) satisfies my conditions.

Comment: Surely it cant be A<4 && A(1:4,4) >= 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically do `A<4` to know which ones are smaller. If you want to know which rows contain `N` values smaller than 4 then you can do

```
rows=find(sum(A<4,2)>=3)
```

This basically does:

- find smaller than 4
- Count how many of them in each row (`sum(_,2)`)
- find if they are 3 or more
- give the row index of those `find()`

Comment: Clear, straightforward one-liner. Thanks.